# Don't feature "I prefer not to work with" just to hide ads

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

As of now, if I don't want to see ads for, say, AngularJS, I need to add it to my "I prefer not to work with" section, which means my profile looks like this:

[image: profile screenshot]

I'd rather not have to publicly show multiple things under "I prefer not to work with", just to hide job ads for such technologies.

Can we separate what we want to hide ads for from what we want shown on our profile?

**Edit:**

[Blorgbeard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard) put it nicely:

> Or, "give me some way to hide ads for a tag without publicly declaring that I'm doing so".

Comment: I don't really understand what's the request here. You want to work with something you explicitly say you don't want to work with? Or you don't want to work with something but don't want to make that public?

Comment: I think the request is: "don't show me ads for things that I haven't explicitly said I want to work with".

Comment: Or, "give me some way to hide ads for a tag without publicly declaring that I'm doing so".

Comment: This is such a confusing question...

Comment: It reads to me like "I'd rather not have prospective clients/employers look at my profile and see a bunch of 'I prefer not to work with' when it really means that I'm just blocking particular ads"

Comment: @NAMS That would be insufficient. If I like X and despise Y, I would like to exclude all jobs that involve Y, even if they also involve X.  I think that's what the asker is getting at.

Comment: Does "I prefer not to work with" mean you're reluctant, or you're unwilling? It's fair to assume recruiters will see it in the worst light since somebody will, and making a big list could mean the candidate will be picky or reluctant to perform work with other technologies they might have to use. Until it's clear, blocking ads will build this list, which sure looks bad to me.